# Magento Frontend Cookie is being duplicated

Tags: php, magento, cookies

When viewing the cookies on my Magento 1.7 site homepage the "frontend" cookie is shown twice.

Examples of the cookies being produced

```
frontend=stpvj4gep5c2h9qu4mhcdlru40;
expires=Wed, 04 Feb 2015 02:21:23 GMT;
path=/; 
domain=.example.com.au; HttpOnly
```

```
frontend=stpvj4gep5c2h9qu4mhcdlru40;
path=/;
domain=example.com.au
```

How do you make it so that only one cookie is being produced?

Comment: Did u fix that issue ? Please share with us :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a [cookie domain](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16349/double-frontend-cookies-causing-intermittent-login-issues) in the Admin Panel. You can find the setting under System -> Configuration -> General / Web / Session Cookie Management: Cookie Domain.